# Sistema não identificando senha criptografada

Tags: php, mysql, criptografia

Então, fiz um sistema em php ligado ao meu mysql onde tem uma tabela chamada `authme` e nela tem as informação de login, como senha, nome e outras coisas mais na hora de logar o sistema não reconhecer a senha criptografada, ai se eu pega a senha ja do jeito que ta no bancos de dados ela entra no sistema

Exemplo
registrei a senha `12345`
criptografada fica `$SHA$50fdc0a77d1689bb$ff363f687bc07e7337bb37dfe994f2f90ac84b185e2b6846b588644325a81884`

e só entra com a senha criptografada

meu codigo

```
<?php 


include("admin/bd/config.php");

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM authme WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

    if ($num == 1) {
        while ($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
            $adm = $percorrer['adm'];
            $username = $percorrer['username'];

            session_start();

            if ($adm == 1) {
                $_SESSION['adm'] = $username;
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "admin/index.php"</script>';
            }else{
                $_SESSION['nor'] = $username;
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "index.php"</script>';
            }


        }
    }else{
        echo "O email ou a senha está errado";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Qual a criptografia que vc tá usando aí ?

Comment: mudei no sistema pra SHA1, mas acho que estou escrevendo errado no codigo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php 
include("admin/bd/config.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM authme WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'";
$resulta = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $get = mysqli_query($CnHUP,"SELECT * FROM authme WHERE username = '$username'");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

    if ($num == 1) {

        while ($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {

            if (password_verify ( $_POST['password'] , $percorrer['password'] )){

                $adm = $percorrer['adm'];
                $username = $percorrer['username'];
                session_start();
                if ($adm == 1) {
                    $_SESSION['adm'] = $username;
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "admin/index.php"</script>';
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['nor'] = $username;
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "index.php"</script>';
                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: $password = sha1($_POST['password']); coloquei esse codigo ai mas ta dando errado

Comment: Entenda antes, de qualquer coisa, que não adianta você criptografar em grego, e tentar capturar em alemão. você tem que critografar em grego para ler grego, e alemão para ler alemão. é como uma pessoa que se comunica com outra, ou você tem um tradutor, ou fala na linguagem da outra pessoa.

Comment: como eu disse eu mudei no sistema pra SHA1, e fiz este codigo mas não que ir

Comment: Vamos lá, no seu campo de senha, dentro do banco de dados, coloque esse valor: 8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964
e no seu campo do formulario, coloque; 12345

* ANTES FAÇA A alteração na que eu propus em minha resposta.

Comment: Me fale o resultado,

Comment: não deu nada amigo

Comment: eu dei var dump e retornou isto 1a7b45ec4c0661b31f3e0cf2f2738d10

Comment: você colocou no campo password, do seu banco de dados esse valor ?8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964 e fez a alteração que propus?
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);// CRIPTOGRAFAR SENHA AQUI

Comment: Então você não está fazendo o que eu pedi.

Comment: você deve estar criptografando até o codigo que eu mandei. rs rs rs

Comment: $password='12345';
sha1 = 8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da9634551396

Comment: Você consegue me chamar para o shat?

Comment: $password = sha1($_POST['password']); fiz isso e tentei usar a senha que o sistema retornou no banco de dados e mesmo assim não vai, ai fui ver no sistema que gera a senha e tem isso aqui   passwordHash: 'SHA256'
  legacyHashes: 
        - 'MD5'

Comment: Alguma coisa errada não está certa.

Comment: Estamos chegando a um consenso... rs rs

Comment: pra te ajudar no passwordhash, preciso saber como está gerando a senha,

Comment: $SHA$aadb6f5d4d0aa464$2d3630eb8b29d40c35cb563f0c8ba89740d8fe3c15d04af8211cc1fb7f1c7f1b = 12345m

Comment: mudei o legacyHashes para SHA1 e n vai

Answer (score 1):

pelo que entendi sua senha no banco está criptografa com sha1, se for isto, em seu post password falta você converter a entrada com a mesma criptografia.

$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

você também pode usar outras alternativas de criptografia como md5() ou hash()

Comment: Não sei se a mesma coisa mais no sistema ta SHA256

Comment: Neste caso então tente sha256($string)!

Comment: Se minha resposta satisfez a solucao de seu problema, marque como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

include("admin/bd/config.php");

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM authme WHERE username = '$username'");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

    if ($num == 1) {

        while ($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {

            if (password_verify ( $_POST['password'] , $percorrer['password'] )){

                $adm = $percorrer['adm'];
                $username = $percorrer['username'];
                session_start();
                if ($adm == 1) {
                    $_SESSION['adm'] = $username;
                    header("Location: admin/index.php");
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['nor'] = $username;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```